# Sigplus and Aidanews2

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have problem with Aidanews2 and Sigplus gallery plugin.

My problem is that, in article there are sigplus gallery added like `{gallery}mygallery{/gallery}`. So the aidanews only shows the plain text `{gallery}mygallery{/gallery}`, but not gallery link.

I have set "Strip Plugins" in aidanews setting to "no", but it still wont work. Any options to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Joomla does not automatically run plugins within a module. The "Strip Plugins" option is supposed to be used to strip out plugin code so it doesn't show up like it is in your case.

In order to make it work, you are going to have to change the the view for the module and have it run any plugins before outputting the content. You can get a pretty good idea of the code you need to add here - http://www.alltogetherasawhole.org/group/developers/forum/topics/running-joomla-content-plugins